# How can a HttpClient be configured for basic - authentification?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I found this sequence to set up basic authentication [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/BasicAuthenticationExample.java?view=markup):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.getState().setCredentials(
   new AuthScope("www.domain.com", 443, "realm"),
   new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password") );
```

How can this be achived by using spring configuration?
The reason behind is, I need to enable authentication for a spring-integration HttpOutboundGateway. 
The only piece of information I found on this topic is [this](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-90833.html)

- The question is: How to do the spring-configuration?
- And second how can I inject the HttpClient into spring-integration?

Comment: HttpClient 3? Why not upgrade to HttpClient 4?

Comment: I decided to use spring-integration 1.0.3 since 2.x wasn't released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it could be something like that: (note, nothing is tested - thats just a series of random thoughts :) )

```
<bean id="httpOutbound" class="org.springframework.integration.http.HttpOutboundEndpoint" >
    <property name="requestExecutor" ref="executor" />
</bean>

<bean id="executor" class="org.springframework.integration.http.CommonsHttpRequestExecutor">
    <property name="httpClient">
        <bean factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="getHttpClient">
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="clientFactory" class="bla.bla.bla.HttpClientFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient" />
    <constructor-arg ref="credentials" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClientParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">
    <property name="authenticationPreemptive" value="true" />
    <property name="connectionManagerClass" value="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="credentials" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
    <constructor-arg value="user" />
    <constructor-arg value="password" />
</bean>


public class HttpClientFactoryBean{
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    public HttpClientFactoryBean(HttpClient httpClient, Credentials credentials){
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        httpClient.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
    }

    public HttpClient getHttpClient(){
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) class of your own which returns HttpClient instances with the configuration you like.